# SVN command line client: checkout refused when LDAP password changed "svn: OPTIONS of" (repo) "authorization failed" (but works in TortoiseSVN)

Tags: login, svn, credentials, authorization, checkout

When using the command line/terminal svn client, a colleague is getting "svn: OPTIONS of " [repo] "...authorization failed" error message when they attempt to checkout the repo to be their local working copy.

They used to be able to do this but have recently had to change their password (periodic routine security policy). And it stopped working. NOTE: The svn check command *does* ask for a password everytime (which they supply - i.e. their new one.)

BUT strangely they have no problem with Tortoise SVN, it works on that. They supply their usual login and *new* password and it works.

Our setup is a virtualised CentOS Linux machine with several Linux user accounts where development takes place and the SVN central repo is on a separate server, authentication is using our LDAP login (i.e. the same corporate login used to login to our Windows machines). We login as Linux users to our development server from our Windows machines, using standard terminal SSH tools, e.g. PuTTY or MobaXTerm or CygWin.

When I change *my* password I don't get the same problem, I am able to checkout.

I have seen many questions about this error message from searching various forums on google but none have provided me with a solution as yet.

One of the solutions I found suggests to clear or remove a local cache containing authentication, in a `.subversion` folder, we tried this but still the same problem. Also tried checking out to another folder.

So it *seems* we have clean out any trace of cached passwords but yet it still rejects.

- Could there be another place on our CentOS Linux machine that caches the login
- What is meant by OPTIONS (could it be a setting somewhere on our development machine or on the SVN repo server?)
- Could it be a HTTP Proxy cache of my colleague's credentials stored somewhere - so we need to clear that when a password is changed?

Comment: CLOSING here and *moving* to programmers.stackexchange.com (this is a development question rather than a user problem - which SU deals with)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in this question relating to programming, it is a question about software.

Comment: @Paul working with SVN (Subversion) usually involves working with code - i.e. programming, because SVN is about version control and is used to control versions of source code used to produce software. That said, SVN can be used to version control kind of files, not just software: documentation, media files etc. But the activity of using SVN is more a development activity and so should belong on programmers.se rather than superuser which deals with users (including power) users of computers, applications and their OSs.

Comment: @therobyouknow we use SVN as a document control system as well as a software versioning.  It's not *just* used by developers... And just because it *might* fit on another Stack site doesn't mean it automatically should be migrated.  I don't see any problem with it staying here.  If on the other hand you *want* it moved you could flag your question and ask a mod to move it for you.